# unable to access hive table in impala

Tags: hive, impala, hadoop-partitioning, hive-partitions

Unable to access hive table in Impala which has partition create on a date column. The data is inserted using dynamic partition column option. 
Now date datatype is not supported in impala. what i should do to access this table in impala. Is there is any option to create timestamp partition in hive if so what is method?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change column type. Two methods:

**1) use [alter table in Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ChangeColumnName/Type/Position/Comment), change type to STRING, etc:**

```
alter table table_name change column col_name col_name string cascade;
```

**2) Alternatively you can change table type to EXTERNAL, drop and recreate with different column type then recover partitions:**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='TRUE');
 DROP TABLE table_name;
 CREATE TABLE ... --change data type as desired
 location... --specify the same location;
```

After you created the table, use this command to create partitions metadata

```
MSCK [REPAIR] TABLE tablename;
```

The equivalent command on Amazon Elastic MapReduce (EMR)'s version of Hive is:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename RECOVER PARTITIONS;
```

This will add Hive partitions metadata. See manual here: [RECOVER PARTITIONS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE))